# ¿Cómo uso "Try with Resources" en conexiones a base de datos?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

No estoy seguro de cómo usar el *"try with resources"* ya que cuando abro una conexión a base de datos, en realidad no solo tendría que cerrar la conexión, sino que también el `PreparedStatment` y el `ResulSet`.

En definitiva, tendría esto:

```
public Producto get(Integer id) throws DataAccessException {
    String query = "select id, item from Producto where id = ?";
    DataSource dataSource = super.getDataSource();
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    Producto producto = new Producto();
                    producto.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                    producto.setItem(resultSet.getString("item"));
                    super.logDebugGet(logger, producto);
                    return producto;
                }
                return null;
            } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
                throw new DataAccessException(sqlException);
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            throw new DataAccessException(sqlException);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        throw new DataAccessException(sqlException);
    }
}
```

Pero me resulta medio reiterativo anidar tantos *try with resources*. Si dejo solamente el try with resources de la conexión, ¿el resto no se cierra automáticamente también? Creo haber leído eso en algún lado aunque sin *try with resources*. Otra cosa que no veo bien es que tenga que poner tantos *catch* con lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer varias asignaciones en la declaración del try:

```java
public Producto get(Integer id) throws DataAccessException {
    String query = "select id, item from Producto where id = ?";
    DataSource dataSource = super.getDataSource();
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)
    ) {
         preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
         //yo aquí prefiero no anidar más y añadir un finally "clásico"
         ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
         while (resultSet.next()) {
             Producto tipoRelacion = new Producto();
             producto.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
             producto.setItem(resultSet.getString("item"));
             super.logDebugGet(logger, producto);
             return producto;
         }
         return null;
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        throw new DataAccessException(sqlException);
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
        }
    }
}
```